# Developing an umbrella framework using flutter plugins as the sub frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, sdk, frameworks

has anyone successfully developed an umbrella framework which is deployed on client app?.

I have requirement where I have to embed flutter plugins as sub frameworks inside the umbrella framework and deploy that umbrella framework on the client side app.

The SDK has dependency on flutter modules/plugins for the functionality and its critical part of the SDK.

The Key requirement is to deploy the SDK with minimal steps on the client side.

The SDK is developed in swift.
There are approx 20-30 flutter plugins to be embedded in the umbrella framework.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem now. Did you manage to solve that?
Looks like umbrella frameworks are not allowed in AppStore. I am trying do use each framework as a binary dependency in Carthage or SPM, but looks like the second one still has lots of issues.